# Поменять содержание на сайте

Tags: html

У меня есть сайтик. Не пойму, куда заходить, чтобы удалить надпись "Добро пожаловать". Вопрос для меня очень сложный, уже два часа сижу, не могу понять, как это сделать.

http://plitochniki.ucoz.ru/

Не разбираюсь в данном вопросе, потому что я слесарь и не программист. Пожалуйста, господа, помогите с вопросом...

Comment: В админ панель вашего сайта заходили? Она тут http://plitochniki.ucoz.ru/admin там вроде как, все должно быть интуитивно понятно, по словам разработчиков юказа.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, это бесплатный сервер и загружается все через ftp. Если сам загружал сервак, то на локалке должен остаться оригинал, если нет, скачай со своего сервера файл index.html или может быть другое расширение. Открой этот файл в блокноте и найди нужную фразу и удали ее. Сохрани файл и скопируй его опять на сервер  с заменой.

Comment: Это укоз, и ничего там не грузится)

По укозу не подскажу, не пользуюсь.